# filemaker xml export via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, loops, filemaker

I'm trying to export some data from our Filemaker Database and transform it via XSLT

I have got most of the way but am getting stuck at some nested data:

Current structure of the XML output is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <PRODUCT BUILD="07-18-2011" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 11.0v4"/>
    <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="D/m/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="bubbles.fp7" RECORDS="34604" TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>
    <METADATA>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="description intro" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Description Line 1" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Description Line 2" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="description short" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="description W3" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Destination URL" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="EAN Code" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="product code W1" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="product group name" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="product name W6" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="stock_for_sale_quantity" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="UPC Code" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="web link standard" TYPE="TEXT"/>
        <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="products_ADDITIONAL_IMAGES::full url" TYPE="TEXT"/>
    </METADATA>
    <RESULTSET FOUND="6">
        <ROW MODID="5678" RECORDID="5051">
            <COL>
                <DATA>description info here</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA> desc line 1</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>desc line 2</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>short description here</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>
Reall long description goes in here</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>url to product</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL> 
                <DATA/>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>SKU</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Acoustic guitars</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>Epiphone EJ-200 Acoustic Guitar Vintage Sunburst EJ200</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>0</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>711106264509</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/15186</DATA>
            </COL>
            <COL>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_01.jpg</DATA>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_02.jpg</DATA>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_03.jpg</DATA>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_04.jpg</DATA>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_05.jpg</DATA>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_06.jpg</DATA>
                <DATA>http://www.mywebsite.co.uk/store/images/uploads/epiej200vsbrst.jpg</DATA>
            </COL>
        </ROW>
```

My XSL is working to a certain extent, but I can't quite get it to pick out each of the images:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <product>
        <product_count>
            <xsl:value-of select="count(//fmp:ROW)"/>
        </product_count>
        <xsl:for-each select="fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:RESULTSET/fmp:ROW">
            <product_info>
                <description_info>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[1]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </description_info>
                <desc_line_1>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[2]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </desc_line_1>
                <desc_line_2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[3]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </desc_line_2>
                <short_description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[4]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </short_description>
                <long_description>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[5]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </long_description>
                <dest_url>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[6]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </dest_url>
                <ean>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[7]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </ean>
                <sku>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[8]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </sku>
                <group_name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[9]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </group_name>
                <product_name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[10]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </product_name>
                <stock_level>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[11]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </stock_level>
                <upc>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[12]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </upc>
                <web_link>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:COL[13]/fmp:DATA"/>
                </web_link>
                <position>
                    <xsl:value-of select="fmp:DATA"/>
                </position>
                <images>
                    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(fmp:COL[14]/fmp:DATA)"/>
                    <image_count>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
                    </image_count>
                    <xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[14]/fmp:DATA[position()&lt;=$count]">
                        <img>
                            <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                        </img>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </images>
            </product_info>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </product>
</xsl:template>
```

This works except for the  bit which gives me the correct number of tags, but no data

```
    <images>
        <image_count>7</image_count>
        <img/>
        <img/>
        <img/>
        <img/>
        <img/>
        <img/>
        <img/>
    </images>
```

Anyone able to help be with the last little loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making things much more complicated than you need to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="fmp:COL[14]/fmp:DATA">
  <img>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </img>
</xsl:for-each>
```

will give you

```
<img>http://www.absolutemusic.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_01.jpg</img>
<img>http://www.absolutemusic.co.uk/store/images/uploads/additional/epiej200vsbrst_02.jpg</img>
....
```

As an aside, I've had to write filemaker XSLTs in the past and to keep myself sane (and not have to remember the right column indexes for each field) I've used a trick like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="mdf" select="/fmp:FMPXMLRESULT/fmp:METADATA/fmp:FIELD" />
<xsl:variable name="descIntro" select="count($mdf[
    following-sibling::fmp:FIELD/@NAME = 'description intro']) + 1" />
<xsl:variable name="descL1" select="count($mdf[
    following-sibling::fmp:FIELD/@NAME = 'Description Line 1']) + 1" />
```

and so on.  This creates a variable for each field name containing the correct index for that field, so you can then use expressions like `fmp:COL[$images]` instead of `fmp:COL[14]`.  This has the additional advantage that if you later change the export definition to include additional fields the XSLT automatically compensates, you don't have to modify all the numbers by hand.

Comment: That solved it - I was definitely looking TOO hard! - going to try the variable naming now - looks excellent. THANKYOU

Comment: That's a neat trick there at the end, but how does it work if I have names like SomeRecord::SomeField ?